# Creating code which generates random mathematical problem for user to solve. Can't figure out the algorithm for calculating correct answer

Tags: python, algorithm

Just learned a bit of phyton language. While having fun with phyton I got stuck on algorithm problem. Couldn't figure out how to **make mathematical notations**, stored in array as strings, **as real mathematical processes** (adding, subtracting, etc.) Also, mathematical notations should **follow the order of operations as in math** (multiplication/division, addition/subtraction). Could somebody try to write an algorithm in section (NOT FINISHED!) **without changing overall code. Variable problem_solved should have the answer for the generated problem.** Would be very greatful. Maybe this site has brilliant minds.

If it's not possible due to a fact how this code is written, let me know :). I'm eager to learn.

**Codes purpose:** generates random mathematical problem for user to solve.

```
from random import randint

#constants
opperators = ["+","-","*","/"]

#variable for program to continue
user_proceed = True

#asking user for the maximum amount of numbers
val = False
while val == False:
    try:
        count_max = int(input("Maximum amount of numbers: "))
        if(count_max < 2):
            print("Has to be greater than 1. ", end = '')
        else:
            #limits user's ability to pick infinite amount of numbers
            if(count_max > 20):
                print("Hold your horses. Pick something a bit easier. ", end = '')
            else:
                val = True
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a valid number! ", end = '')

#program will repeat if procced will be true
while user_proceed == True:

    #generating the count of numbers and opperators
    count_num = randint(2,count_max)
    count_opp = count_num - 1

    #creating arrays for numbers and opperators
    num = [None] * count_num
    opp = [None] * count_opp

    #generating random numbers for problem
    i = -1
    for x in num:
        i = i+1
        if x == None:
            num[i] = randint(1,20) 
        #print(numbers[i]) #for testing purpose

    #generating problem for user to solve
    problem_str = ""
    i = -1
    for x in num:
        i = i+1
        if i == count_opp:
            problem_str = problem_str + str(num[i])
        else:
            opp[i] = opperators[randint(0,3)]
            problem_str = problem_str + str(num[i]) + opp[i]
            #print(opp[i]) #for testing purpose
        #print(problem_str) #for testing purpose


    #calculating solution to the problem (NOT FINISHED!)
    problem_solved = 0

    #asking user for his solution
    print(f"Solve this problem: {problem_str}")
    val = False
    while val == False:
        try:
            user_solution = float(input("Answer: "))
            val = True
        except ValueError:
            print("That's not a valid number! ", end = '')

    #checking if user got the right answer
    if user_solution == problem_solved:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print(f"Wrong! The answer is {problem_solved}")

    #asking user to try again
    print("Try again? ", end='')
    val = False
    while val == False:
        user_answer = input("Yes/No: ")
        if(user_answer != "Yes" and user_answer != "No"):
            print("I don't understand. ", end = '')
        else:
            val = True
            if user_answer == "Yes":
                user_proceed = True
            else:
                user_proceed = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, and congratulations on taking your first steps in programming!

I want to introduce you to one new programming construct, and then one fundamental idea.  The construct is the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).  It stores a key/value lookup. For example if I wanted to store some ages of students, I could do it as follows:

```
age = {
    "Spenser": 17,
    "Alex": 16,
    "Alivia": 14,
    "Zara": 14,
}
```

And a lookup is written `age[student]`, but you read it aloud as "age of student".

The fundamental idea is that learning to program is mostly about learning to structure your thinking in organized ways.  So let's put all of the information that we want about a formula into packages that looks like this:

```
formula1 = {
    "expr": "5 - 3",
    "op": "-",
    "value": 2,
}
formula2 = {
    "expr": "15 / 3",
    "op": "/",
    "value": 5,
}
```

And so on.  Now what do we want to get when we multiply these?

```
formula_times = {
    "expr": "(5 - 3) * 15 / 3",
    "op": "*",
    "value": 10,
}
```

The first note is that, because we know what the operations are, we know where we need parentheses and where not.  The second is that, as we combine them, we are keeping track of both values and expressions in a safe way.  Because we've structured our data, we can also structure our thinking.

Now when do we need to parenthesize?  Please verify that the following makes sense.  For example a `+` expression before a `/` needs parentheses.  A `*` expression does not.  But AFTER a `/`, everything needs parentheses to get the right order of operations.

```
parenthesize_before = {
    "+": "",
    "-": "",
    "*": "+-",
    "/": "+-",
}
parenthesize_after = {
    "+": "",
    "-": "+-",
    "*": "+-",
    "/": "+-*/",
}
```

Now what about a raw number?  We'll need to invent a special op for "no operation".

```
formula_number = {
    "expr": "5",
    "op": "_",
    "value": 5,
}
```

This already works with our "when to parenthesize" logic because you never need parentheses around raw numbers.

And now let's calculate a random formula with 10 numbers in the range `1-20`.

```
from random import choice, random

# Configuration for the formulas
count_num = 10
numbers = list(range(1, 20))


# Operators and parentheses.
operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
parenthesize_before = {
    "+": "",
    "-": "",
    "*": "+-",
    "/": "+-",
}
parenthesize_after = {
    "+": "",
    "-": "+-",
    "*": "+-",
    "/": "+-*/",
}

formulas = []
for i in range(count_num):
    number = choice(numbers)
    formulas.append({
        "expr": str(number),
        "op": "_",
        "value": number,
    })

# While we have multiple formulas
while 1 < len(formulas):
    # Pick 2 at random, removing from the list.
    formula1 = formulas.pop(int(random() * len(formulas)))
    formula2 = formulas.pop(int(random() * len(formulas)))

    # Pick an operator.
    operator = choice(operators)

    # Make sure not to divide by 0.
    if formula2["value"] == 0:
        while operator == "/":
            operator = choice(operators)

    # Do we need to parenthesize formula1?
    if formula1["op"] in parenthesize_before[operator]:
        formula1["expr"] = "(" + formula1["expr"] + ")"

    # Do we need to parenthesize formula2?
    if formula2["op"] in parenthesize_after[operator]:
        formula2["expr"] = "(" + formula2["expr"] + ")"

    formula = {
        "expr": formula1["expr"] + " " + operator + " " + formula2["expr"],
        "op": operator
    }
    if operator == "+":
        formula["value"] = formula1["value"] + formula2["value"]
    elif operator == "-":
        formula["value"] = formula1["value"] - formula2["value"]
    elif operator == "*":
        formula["value"] = formula1["value"] * formula2["value"]
    elif operator == "/":
        formula["value"] = formula1["value"] / formula2["value"]

    # And add it to the list
    formulas.append(formula)


print(formulas[0]["expr"] + " = " + str(formulas[0]["value"]))
```

Now a hint for a problem you'll see.  Do not insist that the user enters your number exactly.  Instead insist on just being close enough.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not clarify why the *without changing overall code. Variable problem_solved should have the answer for the generated problem* rule exists. Are you doing some algorithm problem on some site? Or just created your own problem for fun? If so, why don't you want to change the part of your code?

Secondly, there are two answers for your problem. First one is simple but not a very safe option in the long run. Python has an `exec` function that executes a string as code. So you can just do-

```py
exec(f"problem_solved = {problem_str}")
```

but it is fundamentally a bad idea because you might want to add some imaginary operation or maybe change how operators are represented in Python (`^` instead of `**` for example). In that case `exec` will no longer work.

Harder way, change the problem to *postfix/prefix* notation so that the priority of operations are resolved (more helpful if you use parenthesis in your expression). Then calculate them. And if you use functional breakdowns to create your program, you would not need to change your existing code much.

```py
...
...
problem_solved = solved(problem_str)
...
...

def solved(problem_str):
    postfix = to_postfix(problem_str)
    ...

def to_postfix(problem_str):
    ...
```

You can look at [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm) for changing infix to postfix. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067163/evaluating-postfix-in-python) stack page has kinda good discussion on how to calculate postfix notation using Python.

Edit: Fixed `exec` function usage